# Control on fields restrict in detail page

Tags: custom-field, page-layout, permission-sets, field-level-security, sharing-rule

Is there any wayout to restrict profiles to edit fields from detail page other than FLS and Page layout?

I don't want to have a separate page layout for above case. Also can't change by FLS because there is a commandbutton in a VF page where the concerned profiles if click will update some of these field values.

Please let me know if there is a way?

It would have been good for me if Permission Sets could restrict field accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. You could change FLS to the most restrictive that you need, then use a permission set for users assigned to the profile that you want to have the additional permissions which grants them those permissions. You'd also want to create a 2nd command button to use on a unique page layout for the profile that doesn't have more extensive permissions.

However, the above is really no different than changing the FLS on the profile that needs to be more restrictive. Either way, a command button shouldn't be allowing those users to change fields that you don't want them to have access to. As such, they need to have their own page layout with a unique command button or with no button at all on it for them.